# Versioning of DLLs in .NET Core project based on different cloud providers

Tags: c#, .net-core, cloud

I am using tow cloud providers i.e. Azure and AWS based on the project I need to create the versioning of Dlls so that only respective cloud provider will pick the correct Dlls. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.